# Installing the Social Bookmarks plugin for Publify blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, publify

I'm trying to install and configure [the social bookmarks plugin for the Publify blogging](https://github.com/typoplugins/social_bookmark) engine, but I'm just getting an error when the page loads.

I've unzipped the plugin to /vendors/plugins/social-bookmarks

I've added the following to my template but I'm just getting an error page when trying to view my blog

```
<%= render_social_bookmarks(@article, @article.title) %>
```

Comment: Why didn't you paste this error message? It can REALLY help us to find out the solution.

Comment: I'm not sure how to obtain the error message, I've checked the production.log but nothing is there. I'll update the question with a link to the broken page but it doesn't give much information.

Comment: How about trying it out in development? That's what it is for.

Comment: I'll give it a go, off to google to find out how to switch to development mode :)

Comment: It would probably best for you if you run development mode on your local machine. It would be convenient and really useful when you want to debug your app - just like now.